# crop image with specific resolution in image in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, selection

i want to crop an image with specific resolution for example h*w*3.

[image: picture]

In the above image red image is original image. blue part is the selection of a portion of image with specific size. it can able to move around the image and crop the portion. how to do this in matlab? in matlab selection tool is there to select the portion, but we don't no which size we are selecting. how to do this. kindly help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function imcrop 
(see : http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imcrop.html#buxpscv-1)

Specifically, look at:
I2 = imcrop(I,rect) 
rect is a four-element position vector of the form [xmin ymin width height] that specifies the **size** and **position** of the **crop rectangle**. imcrop returns the cropped image, I2.

Hope this helps.